# Show that the composition operator is a bounded linear operator.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, operator-theory, normed-spaces

**Problem:** Fix a continuous function $\phi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ and define the operator $C_\phi:C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ by $(C_\phi f)(x)=f(\phi(x)).$ Prove that this is a bounded linear operator with $\|C_\phi\|\le1$.

**Attempt:** Consider $\|C_\phi\|_{op}$, now,

$$\|C_\phi\|_{op}=\sup\{\|C_\phi f\|_\infty:f\in C([0,1])\}=\sup\{\sup\{|(C_\phi f)(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}:f\in C([0,1])\}$$

Regard the "inner supremum" on it's own for the time being. Using the definition of $C_\phi$ we see that,

$$\sup\{|(C_\phi f)(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}=\{\sup\{|f(\phi(x))|:x\in[0,1]\}$$

Since $\phi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ it is clear that $\phi(x)=y$ where $y\in[0,1]$, we get that,

$$\sup\{|f(\phi(x))|:x\in[0,1]\}=\sup\{|f(y)|:y\in[0,1]\}=\|f\|_\infty$$

So that, going back to the "sup of the sup" we had before,

$$\sup\{\sup\{|(C_\phi f)(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}:f\in C([0,1])\}=\sup\{\|f\|_\infty:f\in C([0,1])\}=\|f\|_\infty$$

But then, putting this all together, we have that $\|C_\phi\|_{op}=\|f\|_\infty$, and I don't believe that this is right. I think that it is, rather, an incorrect means to approach the problem.

--

On the other hand if we just considered,

$$\|C_\phi f\|_\infty=\sup\{|(C_\phi f)(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}=\sup\{|f(y)|:y\in[0,1]\}=\|f\|_\infty$$

So that in particular, $\|C_\phi f\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty$ which would mean that $\|C_\phi\|_{op}=1$. Now saying that something is equal to something does still satisfy saying that it is less than or equal to something. So I have to wonder, is this sufficient to answer the problem? Or have I done something wrong, this second time round, which has made it seem easier than it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since linearity is trivial, all you have left to prove is $\forall f\in C([0,1]), \|C_{\phi}f\|\leq\|f\|$.

Note that $\{|f(\phi(x))|, x\in [0,1]\}\subset \{|f(x)|, x\in [0,1]\}$, thus $$\sup\{|f(\phi(x))|, x\in [0,1]\}\leq \sup \{|f(x)|, x\in [0,1]\}$$

which rewrites as $\|C_{\phi}f\|\leq\|f\|$.

Comment: This is a very nice and elucidating reasoning. Should the $"\subset"$ not be $"\subseteq"$?

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames I always use $\subset$ to denote inclusion in the large sense, and you're right, there is no reason for it to be strict.